# selenium python webdriver xpath error

Tags: python, selenium

http://www.m2sys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Learn-More-btn-new2.png.      I want to test this website's image button with selenium python but it failed.  What will be the xpath for the image source?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use xpath's `contains` method.

```
//img[contains(@src, 'Learn-More-btn-new2.png')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`xpath` for the **`LEARN MORE`** button will be :

```
//img[@src='http://www.m2sys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Learn-More-btn-new2.png']
```